# C# ASP.NET : Issue with check box and radio button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating an app where the users fill a form where the setting of some properties are not mandatory. This includes check boxes and radio buttons.

So, I have something like this in my model:

```
public class MyModel {
     public bool boolvalue;
     public MyTwoValuedType mytypevalue;
}
```

and I have in the view:

```
@model MyModel

<form method="post">
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.boolvalue)

   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.mytypevalue, mytypevalue.Value1)

   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.mytypevalue, mytypevalue.Value2)
</form>
```

When I initialize the view I send an empty model through `return View();` in the controller, and the radio buttons have no value (no radio button checked) and the check box is not checked (so its value is false).
However, I would like to use nullable types, like (`bool?` and `MyTwoValuedType?`), once that I want that if the submission of the form (in the View) is made without the user have changed the value of the check boxes and radio buttons, they don't get a default value. Even when the submission of the form has an error, the reappearance of the form (because fails validation) has values in the check boxes and radio buttons that were not set by the user…

Should I use `Html.DropDownListFor` with nullable types instead of check boxes and radio buttons? Would this have a good result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use @Html.DropDownListFor for nullable properties** because when you send empty model in view and then in POST you will get false as boolean return.
You cannot use checkbox for boolean model.

And if you want to use checkbox and radio for boolean then use jquery to set value.
but DropdownList is Best for boolean model property.

Answer (score 2):

So regarding the use of `nullable` boolean in a check-boxes, it is not suitable since a `nullable` boolean value can store 3 states: `null`, `true` and `false`. But a checkbox can only have a `true` or a `false` on it its control. This is because a `HTML Checkbox` does not have 3-state support because at that time, this concept was not there. It shares the property with the old Windows Forms Checkbox. So you need to use a `dropdownlist` to handle the three states. If you want to use check-boxes then:

- stop using `nullable` booleans

OR

- stop trying to use a `checkbox` because then the `null` state would be converted to `false`

Answer (score 1):

You said: *"I send an empty model through return View()"* - check if the model is null.

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     return View();
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(Models.MyModel m)
 {
     return View(m);
 }
```

**View:**

```
<form method="post">
    @{

        if (Model == null)
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.boolvalue)

            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.mytypevalue,false);

            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.mytypevalue,false)
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.boolvalue)

            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.mytypevalue, Model.mytypevalue.Value1);

            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.mytypevalue, Model.mytypevalue.Value2)
        }
    }
</form>
```

**Model:**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool boolvalue;
    private MyTwoValuedType _mytypevalue;
    public MyTwoValuedType mytypevalue
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mytypevalue == null)
            {
                _mytypevalue = new MyTwoValuedType();
            }
            return _mytypevalue;
        }
        set
        {
            _mytypevalue = value;
        }
    }
}
```